Enums in AWS AppSync schema.graphql
How can I create an enum keys in AppSync with values?
I've tried both:
enum Reason {
    Duplicate="duplicate",
    Fraudulent="fraudulent",
    RequestedByCustomer="requested_by_customer",
    Abandoned="abandoned"
}

enum Reason {
    Duplicate:"duplicate",
    Fraudulent:"fraudulent",
    RequestedByCustomer:"requested_by_customer",
    Abandoned:"abandoned"
}

the only way it worked was,
enum Reason {
    duplicate,
    fraudulent,
    requested_by_customer,
    abandoned
}

and this is something I don't want.
